# How to get date range for one day using strftime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am pulling data from a third party api where we have to provide a date range for the data. Below is how to apply the date range I am confused in how i do the `startDate` so it is yesterdays date?

```
params = {
        "queryId": query_id,
        "startDate": "2020-01-01",
        "endDate": datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "pageSize": "5000"
    }
```

I want the `startdate` to be set to yesterday's date.

Comment: Btw, you can use `str(date.today())` and `str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1))`, it will return date in required format. It will be a bit better, cause if you don't care about time, you should use [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) class. Also simple cast to `str` will be faster than custom formatting.

Comment: What did you try? Please see https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Or what exactly are you "confused" about, or specifically what about the docs is unclear? (perhaps they could be reworded if ambiguities are made known..

Comment: @SherylHohman Tried the below answer and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(today)     # 2020-08-13

yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(yesterday) # 2020-08-12
```

---

The possibilities with `timedelta` are

```
timedelta(days=1)
timedelta(seconds=1)
timedelta(microseconds=1)
timedelta(milliseconds=1)
timedelta(minutes=1)
timedelta(hours=1)
timedelta(weeks=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timedelta` object to solve this problem.

From python's official documentation,

> #### Description
>
> *A **timedelta** object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.*
>
> #### Syntax
>
> *class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)*

So, You can use `timedelta` object to represent 1 day and then subtract it from the current day to get the date of yesterday. The solution will be as follows,

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  # Make sure to import timedelta

params = {
        "queryId": query_id,
        "startDate": datetime.strftime(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1), "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "endDate": datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "pageSize": "5000"
    }
```

- More about timedelta [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations & give an indication of what limitations & assumptions apply. If the Q has already been answered, a link to that SO post should be written in the comments , or report the post as a duplicate, instead of re-answering for SO to function as designed.

Comment: @SherylHohman Thank you for your support. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `"endDate"` is today

```
datetime.today()
```

then yesterday can just be one day less than that

```
datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
```

You can obviously pass this into `datetime.strftime` for `"startDate"` the same way you do for `"endDate"`